# Splitting a cell column value before comparison

Tags: excel, vba

I have two spreadsheets, vda.xlsx and main.xlsm. At the moment I'm comparing the values in:

*main.xlsm column J*

with

*vda.xlsx column A*

To see if there is a match. If a match is found then the value in column gets highlighted in red.

However the format of the data in vda.xlsx column A has changed .

It used to look like this

*1234*

Now it looks like this

*Test\1234* or *Best\1234* or *Jest\1234* - it could be anything...

Sp I need to split Test\1234 by the "\" and extract 1234 for comparison.

Any idea how I can accomplish this. This is my code so far:

```
Sub VDA_Update()

Dim wshT As Worksheet
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wshS As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Dim m As Long
    Dim cel As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wshT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Check whether vda.xlsx is already open
    Set wbk = Workbooks("vda.xlsx")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If wbk Is Nothing Then
        ' If not, open it
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Working\vda_test.xlsx")
    End If

    ' Set worksheet on vda.xlsx
    Set wshS = wbk.Worksheets("imac01")
    m = wshT.Cells(wshT.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop though cells in column J on main.xlsm
    For r = 1 To m
        ' Can we find the value in column C of vda.xlsx?

        Set cel = wshS.Columns(1).Find(What:=wshT.Cells(r, 10).Value, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not cel Is Nothing Then

            ' If we find a match, then change the text to red
            wshT.Cells(r, 10).Font.ColorIndex = 3

        End If
    Next r

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: clarify please, your `main` workbook contains `1234`, and your `vda` workbook contains data like `test\1234` and you need to determine, whether  `1234` (from `main` wb) is in column `A` of `vda` workbook (in format `test\1234`)?

Comment: I need to see if `1234` can be found in `test\1234` (yes it can), by splitting it into an array and retrieving the last item in the array (as the answer below shows)

Comment: It's clear, but which workbook contains `1234` and which `test\1234`?

Comment: main.xlsm contains `1234` and uat.xlsx contains `test\1234`

Comment: It appears that the code below isn't working, I get a runtime error 9 at `Set cel = wshT.Columns(10).Find(cellSplit(UBound(cellSplit)), _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Split(CellValue, "\")` to get an array and then retrieve the last item in the array.

Change:

```
' Loop though cells in column J on main.xlsm
For r = 1 To m
    ' Can we find the value in column C of vda.xlsx?

    Set cel = wshS.Columns(1).Find(What:=wshT.Cells(r, 10).Value, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not cel Is Nothing Then

        ' If we find a match, then change the text to red
        wshT.Cells(r, 10).Font.ColorIndex = 3

    End If
Next r
```

To something like:

```
' Loop though cells in column A on vda.xlsx
For r = 1 To m
    ' Can we find the value in column J of main.xlsm?

    cellSplit = Split(wshS.Cells(r, 1).Value, "\")
    Set cel = wshT.Columns(10).Find(cellSplit(UBound(cellSplit)), _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not cel Is Nothing Then

        ' If we find a match, then change the text to red
        cel.Cells(1, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3

    End If
Next r
```

Comment: @Antoine-LaurentLavoisier, added an example of how you could do this. May contain some bugs though

Comment: I get a runtime error at `Set cel = wshT.Columns(10).Find(cellSplit(UBound(cellSplit)), _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)`